# PHP: check if string contain the same word more than once

Tags: php

I have to check if string contains http or https more than once.

For example:

```
https://plus.google.com/share?url=https://example.com/test/
```

Or it can be:

```
https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://example.com/test/
```

The `http` and the `https` can be mixed

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, since if your string contains "https", then it also contains "http", you can directly count the occurrences of "http", for example by using the function [substr_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php):

```
if(substr_count($your_string, "http") > 1) {
  // do something
}
else {
  // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more performant version using `strpos()` and `strrpos()`:

```
$appears_more_than_once = strpos($string, 'http') !== strrpos($string, 'http');
```

Checks if first instance and last are not the same.

Comment: I'd already used `substr_count` and figured there should be a faster method - this is it. Searching in a 50mb string, it's between 2.5 to 4 times faster (depending on whether the substring occurs once or many times)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `preg_match_all()` which returns the number of matches found.

```
if (preg_match_all('/http|https/', $searchString) > 1) {
    print 'More than one match found.';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex to search for both *http* and *https*:

```
$text = "http://plus.google.com/share?url=https://example.com/test/";
preg_match_all('/https?/', $text, $matches);
if (count($matches[0]) > 1) {
    // More than one match found.
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).
strpos returns the position of first occurrence of a substring in a string.
To find all the occurrences call strpos repeatedly, passing the return value of last strpos call + length of substring as the offset.

```
 function countOccurences($haystack,$needle) {
    $count = 0;
    $offset = 0;
    while(($pos = strpos($haystack,$needle,$offset)) !== FALSE) {
        $count++;
        $offset = $pos + strlen($needle);
        if($offset >= strlen($haystack)) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return $count;
 }

echo countOccurences("https://plus.google.com/share?url=https://example.com/test/","http");
```